# List all running Taskbar applications with .NET

Tags: .net

I'm trying to get a list of all the applications that are running, but not every process: just the applications that show up in the taskbar.

You used to be able to just get a list of processes using `Process.GetProcesses()`, and then only show ones where `MainWindowTitle` isn't blank or `MainWindowHandle` isn't 0. That doesn't really work anymore because `MainWindowTitle` is blank and `MainWindowHandle` is 0 for many applications that show in the taskbar.

Can anyone recommend a way I can filter processes out of this list that wouldn't show up in the taskbar, like system and background processes? Or is there another way to only get processes that show in the taskbar?

Comment: Application that show up in what *part* of the TaskBar? Just the TaskList container (`MSTaskListWClass`)? Try with `var windows = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Window));` and loop the `windows` collection of AutomationElements. -- Have you tested `EnumWindows()` by chance? Can that work for you or there's something missing?

Comment: See https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2021/04/this-uses-inbuilt-compilers-in-windows.html. *Windows that are normal, a titlebar with a system menu, appear on the taskbar. Windows that want to appear on the taskbar but don't meet the requirements can set an extended window's style of an AppWindow.*. To enumerate Windows See https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/05/winlistexe-list-open-windows-and-their.html.

Comment: @user18521918 Naa, you never use `GetWindow()` for this, it's unreliable and also quite *dangerous*. The risk to dead-lock is too high. `EnumWindows()` (or `EnumDesktopWindows()`, depending on the context) can do the job. UI Automation also can. It depends on what you're looking for.